# GCP AI Platform custom prediction routine fails downloading nltk resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nltk, google-cloud-ml

I created my custom prediction routine for an email classifier. At pre-processing, I'm using nltk. Model creation is successful but when I send a request, GCP fails to download required nltk files. When my preprocessing file is like this

```
import nltk

class MyPreprocess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def to_sentences(self, text):
        sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
nltk.download('punkt')
Attempted to load [93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle[0m
```

And if I will add `nltk.download('punkt')` after import statement, I'm getting another error like this:

```
ERROR:root:Unexpected error when loading the model: problem in predictor - OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/root/nltk_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE: CURRENT SOLUTION

Apparently, inside ai-platform models, working directory is ''. This directory is read-only and you can't download anything here. I just changed download path of nltk punkt to `tmp` and it worked. `nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='/tmp')`

### PREVIOUS TEMPORARY SOLUTION

I did a temporary workaround but I don't believe this is a good way of solving this problem:

Before deploying model, I downloaded nltk punkt locally , and located `english.punkt` file. Then in my preprocessing code I loaded it manually.

```
from nltk.data import load

class MyPreprocess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nltk_tokenizer = load('english.punkt')
    
    def sentence_tokenizer(self, text):
        return self.nltk_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

With this way, already loaded tokenizer will be packed up into the pickle file so that not need to download punkt during deployment.